# How to say: to check presence of something

Tags: word-usage

Tom wants to check, if he has his nobile phone with him. Could I say then:

```
Tom put his hand to his pocket to check for his mobile.
```

Comment: Your sentence is good as is.

Answer (score 2):

Could be shortened to just "Tom checked his pocket for his phone." The fact that it was a cell or cordless phone and that he used his hand to do it would be obvious to virtually everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You could write it as "Tom put his hand **into** his pocket to check for his mobile".
Another better way to say this will be :
"Tom reached for his pocket to check for his mobile".

Comment: You cannot really "reach for your pocket".  You can reach for your pen, or reach for your gun.  *Reach for* implies the item is nearby, not on one's person.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the item is nearby or on you. Reach for means extending one's grasp to something. It can be your pocket too.

Comment: @TRomano: cargo pants?  It's either a reach or a leg lift with those to get the lower pockets. :)

Comment: You can only reach for something that you can take up and hold in your hand. That's true even when one is told to "reach for the sky, pardner". Pocketses don't qualify.  :-)

Comment: Even "to his pocket" (as is written in the question) is fine as if he is just touching the outside of the pocket to feel through the fabric. I do that frequently, especially in winter when I'm wearing gloves and might not be able to get my hands *into* my pockets.